# Java regex for definite or any character less than 11

Tags: regex

I am a Rails developer but I need a regular expression that can allow a shortcode or any set of characters not more than 11 in total.
I was thinking something like:

```
(7575|[0-9a-zA-Z& ]*{11})
```

However, it has not worked.

Comment: Could you provide an example of a string that would match the desired regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what function you are using (this matters because `find` and `matches` behave differently), but to make things unambiguous, you can use the following:

```
^(7575|[0-9a-zA-Z& ]{1,11})$
```

The above means either match `7575` or match between 1 to 11 characters from the character set `0-9a-zA-Z&` . If you want to allow an empty string as well, you will have to use `{0,11}` instead.

A slightly more memory efficient one would be `^(?:7575|[0-9a-zA-Z& ]{1,11})$` (since there are no capture groups).

`^` matches the beginning of the string and `$` matches the end of the string, thus ensuring there are no more characters before or after the matched part.

Comment: The question is - why leave `7575` in the pattern? It is matched by the more general pattern behind.

Comment: @nhahtdh I didn't notice that indeed. Good question to OP.

Answer (score -1):

Further more memory efficient regex

```
"^(7575|[\w]{1,11})$"
```

where \w is A word character, short for [a-zA-Z_0-9]

Comment: `_` is not in the question - why include it implicitly?